# How to increase the timing of a Fade animation in flutter using a counter method?

Tags: flutter

I tried to implement a method on my fadeIn animation that increments the time in which each widget its showing. I want to do that automatically, so if i add one more widget, I dont have to manually set the delay of showing it, but just adding the counter method so it increases ++ for each widget. This is what I done so far:

```
enum AniProps { opacity, translateX }

class FadeIn extends StatefulWidget {
  final int delaySecs;
  final Widget child;


  FadeIn(this.delaySecs, this.child);

  @override
  _FadeInState createState() => _FadeInState();
}

class _FadeInState extends State<FadeIn> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var counter = 0;
    void incrementCounter() {
      setState(() {
        counter ++;
        print('Counter added');
        return counter.toInt();
      });
    }
    const durationSecs = 0.5;
    const opacityFade = 0.0;
    const translateXFade = 130.0;
    final tween = MultiTween<AniProps>()
      ..add(AniProps.opacity, opacityFade.tweenTo(1.0))
      ..add(AniProps.translateX, translateXFade.tweenTo(0.0));

    return PlayAnimation<MultiTweenValues<AniProps>>(
      delay: (widget.delaySecs).round().seconds,
      duration: durationSecs.seconds,
      tween: tween,
      child: widget.child,
      builder: (context, child, value) => Opacity(
        opacity: value.get(AniProps.opacity),
        child: Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(value.get(AniProps.translateX), 0),
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Its not really working because i cannot wrap my widgets with a method:

```
Fade in (increasecounte, 
container(................))
```

Please help.